# Converting to php MySQLi Object-Oriented

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to convert my website to MySQLi object-oriented:
Below works. Before I convert my site is there anything I've missed or need to do better or differently?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT pagename, image, name FROM table";

$result = $db->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
?>

<figure>
<a href="<?php echo ($row['pagename']); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo ($row['image']); ?>"></a>
<figcaption>
<a href="<?php echo ($row['pagename']); ?>">
<h2><?php echo ($row['name']); ?></h2></a>
</figcaption>
</figure>

<?php
}
$result->free();
$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: use a prepared statement if there's any user intervention

Comment: Do not confuse object syntax and OOP. There is no OOP in your code.

Comment: First you should split presentation and logic. Mixing them is asking for trouble in the long run. As Your Common Sense says, you are not really taking advantage of any OOP principles here either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no real problem here, and it's only appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, if anything.